# Converting an Access database to SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access, visual-studio-2012

I am a programmer and am wanting to undertake a project of converting an Access database to an SQL database.

Is this pretty easy to do? Can I just use a tool to create all the tables with the same names and 'copy' over the data?

I know that Access has built in reporting features. Does SQL have these reporting features? If not, is it easy to create them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to import your access to sql server database.

Check this tutorial:

[Importing Microsoft Access 2007 Database Tables into SQL Server](http://www.fmsinc.com/MicrosoftAccess/SQLServerUpsizing/importing/Import_Access_DB.asp)

Regards

Answer (score 1):

MS Access is not a database at all, by default, it uses the Jet or ACE database to store data, but Access will also work perfectly well with data stored in a number of other databases, MS SQL included. There is no need to change from an MS Access front-end when you are moving the tables to a new back-end. SQL Server does not have all the user-interface and reporting tools that MS Access has, it *is* a database, not "a rapid application database development and reporting tool"

Answer (score 0):

Try [this](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=28763) one its free from [microsoft](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/en/us/product-info/migration-tool.aspx#Access).